# how to pull all the available snapshots versions from nexus repository to the Jenkins?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, bitbucket, nexus

I am trying the maven repository connector plugin but all i am getting is only one SNAPSHOT i.e. 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.
Though the nexus repository have 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT,1.0.1.SNAPSHOT and 1.0.2.SNAPSHOT. all the versions have multiple builds. Now my requirement is to pull the specific build zip file from the SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the problem by 
1. Uninstalled the repository connector plugin.
2. restart the Jenkins.
3. restart the nexus server.
4. install plugin again and configure the plugin with nexus Url.